# file scan using fscanf with array struct in c

Tags: c, file, struct

So i wanna know how to use fscanf with array struct. So this is my struct

```
struct menuinput{
        char nama[50];
        int nomor;
        int berat;
        int jumlah;
        int pilihan;
        float kalori;
        float totalkkal;
    }mknpokok[20],mknsayur[20],mknspsj[20],mknlaukpauk[20],mknbuah[20];
```

And i wanna use it in file scan using fscanf, as far as i know file scan command is like this

```
while(!feof(fp))    
{
        fscanf(fp,"\n%d %[^\n] %d %.3f",&mknpokok.nomor[i],mknpokok.nama[i],&mknpokok.berat[i],&mknpokok.kalori[i])
        i++;
}
```

When i run that i get this error message

```
error: '(struct menuinput *)&mknpokok' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?
```

I forget how to fscanf with array struct, so is what am i doing is correct? if wrong please correct it with the right code, thank you.

Comment: What about the file scan? how to replace `while(!feof(fp)){fgets(stream,sizeof stream,fp);}` with fscanf? @SupportUkraine

Comment: @LearnerC Did you try the suggestions in the answers you've gotten?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the elements of the `struct` `mknpokok` in a wrong way.

You should access them like `&mknpokok[i].nomor` instead of `&mknpokok.nomor[i]`, since you have declared array of `mknpokok`, not `nomor`.

Answer (score 0):

- You have placed the subscript operator on the wrong elements. `mknpokok` is an array of `20` `menuinput` so use the subscript operator on that, `mknpokok[i]`.
- Never use `while(!feof(stream))` and then try to read from the stream without checking that reading succeeded. See [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)
- You should always make sure that you don't read more elements than you can fit in your array. Always do bounds checking.
- `%.3f` is not a standard conversion. You should probably use `%f`.

Example:

```c
//   only populate elements 0-19
//              v
    while (i < 20 && fscanf(fp, " %d %[^\n] %d %f", &mknpokok[i].nomor,
                            mknpokok[i].nama, &mknpokok[i].berat,
                            &mknpokok[i].kalori) == 4) {
//                                               ^^^^
//                                    check that fscanf succeeded
        ++i;
    }
```